# Question closed as duplicate, but no dupe given

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

[Windows 8 Login Screen shows two login tiles for same user account](https://superuser.com/questions/501746/windows-8-login-screen-shows-two-login-tiles-for-same-user-account) was closed as an exact duplicate, but no duplicate was given. Explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user [edited the note out of the question](https://superuser.com/posts/501746/revisions). It's restored now.